# how to read sheet no 2 from csv file in ruby on rails and nodejs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, csv

I wrote a **CSV file** in excel with multiple sheets like ***sheet1*, *sheet2*, *sheet3*** having different information and now I want to read CSV file. How can I access information in **sheet2, sheet3 ...**, using `ruby on rails` and `Nodejs`.

Comment: When you "save as CSV" from Excel, you are asked to confirm which sheet you want to save, and Excel saves only a single sheet in the CSV file. AFAIK you cannot save multiple sheets in a single CSV file.

Comment: Yes, I observe that. anyway thanks for time

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps using a more appropriate tool for the job might help you, there are numerous tools available, my favourite is RubyXL it will simply allow you to iterate through work sheets or work with specific sheet.

e.g.
Gemfile

```
gem 'rubyXL'
```

then from the command line install the gem

```
bundle install
```

To open a spreadsheet

```
xlfile = RubyXL::Parser.parse('my_xl_file')
```

Obviously replacing 'my_xl_file' with whatever path your xl file lives in plus the file name

And to read a sheet by name

```
xlsheet = xlfile['WorkSheetName']
```

Or to iterate through the sheets you can use, by sheet position

```
xlsheet = xlfile[０]
```

or
    xlsheet = workbook.first
    xlsheet = workbook.next

use .count to get the number of sheets if you want to loop then to access cells you just need the row, col (row,col) e.g. the first cell

```
row = 1
col = 1
cell_value = xlsheet[row][col].value
```

read more here https://github.com/weshatheleopard/rubyXL

Similarly there is also the spreadsheet gem if the above doesn't suit. This will work with propritary xls files in a similar way

https://github.com/zdavatz/spreadsheet

so to answer your question

> how to read sheet no 2 from csv file in ruby on rails and nodejs

My answer is "don't", Please use a better tool for the job

But if you really need to use nodeJS then the following should help

> By default it reads the first sheet in the document. If you have
>   multiple sheets in your spreadsheet then pass either sheet: number
>   (sheet index, starting from 1) or sheet: string (sheet name) as part
>   of the options argument (options.sheet is 1 by default):

```
readXlsxFile(file, { sheet: 2 }).then((data) => {
  ...
})
```

The above taken from https://www.npmjs.com/package/read-excel-file